# Prestashop: Producto with price 0 in category page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop 1.6 web.

I have this product, with a price of 19€. The product page is showing the correct price.
http://batavia.es/es/escuadra-y-cartabon-2395.html

But the price is 0 in the category page:
http://batavia.es/es/unisex-116158?p=2

I have this problem only with this product. I have checked the product in admin panel, and it seems correct. The product have not discounts or specific prices. I have debugged the php object, and it has the price attribute to 0.

Anything that I can try?

Thanks.

Comment: Remove and re-add the product :). Clear cache from the backoffice, maybe it's a template problem.

Answer (score 0):

The product price can be fetched using the getPriceStatic() function in Product.php class file, you can try debugging this function for the product  which is causing the issue.

You might be able to find the problem with that product.